# Disabling language prefix for route in module

Tags: 8, routes, i18n-l10n

How can I disable the automatic redirect to the language prefixed URL for a URL defined in a `routing.yml` in my module?

I'm developing a custom sitemap.xml module, because the Simple Sitemap XML module does not have the options I need. I've got it just about working, except the URL `/sitemap.xml` 301 automatically redirects to the URL `/lang/sitemap.xml` - and it really shouldn't. How can I disable this redirect?

Comment: Do you have the Redirect module installed?

Comment: In language detection settings, disable the url prefix or assign it larger weight.

Comment: The 3.x branch of [simple_sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap) supports {variant}/sitemap.xml and also implements the no-redirect directive you are asking about. What functionality are you missing from it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, has to be redirect.module, core doesn't do that. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2854462#comment-12047347, just add the '_disable_route_normalizer' flag to your route and you should be fine.

module_sitemap.routing.yml:

```
module_sitemap.sitemap:
  path: '/sitemap.xml' 
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\module_sitemap\Controller\SitemapController::view'
    _title: 'View Site Map'
    _disable_route_normalizer: 'TRUE'
```

Comment: I've tried adding this flag both in the options section, and the root in my routing.yml:

`  options:
    _disable_route_normalizer: 'TRUE'
  _disable_route_normalizer: 'TRUE'`

Neither appears to work. Am I doing it wrong, or do I have to add it in a hook somewhere?

Comment: " $route->setDefault('_disable_route_normalizer', TRUE);", which means it is in the defaults section, not options or root

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I edited in the code that worked.